# Script keeps on saving the value even when unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, variables, text, download

I want the script to save the value of the text only when it's checked.
If possible I also want to save the value of it only when it's clicked as a variable so I can do this for example
Name: {here the variable} #if checked

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Feedback</title>

<script language="Javascript" >
function download(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

  pom.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(pom);

  pom.click();

  document.body.removeChild(pom);
}

function addTextHTML()
{
    document.addtext.name.value = document.addtext.name.value + ".html"
}

function addTextTXT()
{
    document.addtext.name.value = document.addtext.name.value + ".txt"
}
</script>

</head>
<body>



<form name="addtext" onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">

<input type="checkbox" name="text" id="test" value=name> 
<label for="test">Test</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="File Name">
<input type="submit" onClick="addTextHTML();" value="Save As HTML">
<input type="submit" onClick="addTexttxt();" value="Save As TXT">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `break;`. But it will give error and you'll be able to see it on console.
So try something like this;

```js
var text = "";
      var a;
      for (a = 1; a < 2; a++){
      //code will be here which gets in the loop
      text += "Working";
      }

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content = "ie=edge">
        <title> Keat </title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will make loop to but it will restrict the loop.